# Direkt Link to ID & Class with html/css

Tags: html, css

I have a Button on my Page that toggles front-View like such:

```
<div id="toggleFrontView">
    <span class="cats"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i> Stöbern</span>
    <span class="search active"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Suchen</span>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do now is create a html-link from somewhere to link to the toggled View "Stöbern".

Like such:

```
<a href="#toggleFrontView">link</a>
```

Unfortunately this does scroll to the anchor point, but does not toggle the view.
Can someone help?

Thanks
Flo

Comment: "toggled View" is not a feature of HTML or CSS. You probably have some JavaScript to implement it. You would have to modify that JavaScript to support checking the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Javascript or JQuery. U cant do this only with HTML and CSS.
in jquery there is a toggle display method...
(There are many examples on the net. just give a search before asking a question)

```
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="toggleFrontView">toggle section</div>

<div id="clk">click me</div>

<script>
   $( "#clk" ).click(function() {
      $("#toggleFrontView").toggle();
   });
</script>
```

Comment: just need the reason for down vote... :P
This is for exactly what you have asked for. Instead of down voting, change your question if required...

Comment: I did not know, js was necessary, hence my question.

Thanks for your support, I will try finding a js-example. The one above did not work for me.

Comment: Sorry not on purpose!
Nervous coffee-fingers ;-)

Comment: it needs Jquery to be loaded. If you didnt add it. I've added it to my example.

Comment: Ah ok!
Thanks! Not enough reputation to upvote you ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right. There is some angular behind it.
Unfortunately I do not understand it.
Here it is:

```
// Search / cats home
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#searchBase').addClass('vis');
        }, 500)

        $('#toggleFrontView .cats').click(function () {

            var toggle = $('#toggleFrontView .cats'),
                searchBtn = toggle.find('.search'),
                catBtn = toggle.find('.cats'),
                filterCats = $('#filterCategories'),
                searchHead = $('#searchHead'),
                searchBase = $('#searchBase'),
                catItem = $('.catItem');

            toggle.addClass('active');
            $('#toggleFrontView .search').removeClass('active');

            filterCats.addClass('vis');
            searchBase.removeClass('vis');
            searchBtn.addClass('vis');
            //catBtn.addClass('hidden');

            searchHead.find('h1').removeClass('vis');
            searchHead.find('h2').addClass('vis');

            loop_();
            function loop_() {
                animateIn = setTimeout(function () {

                    $(catItem[0]).addClass('vis');
                    catItem.splice(0, 1);

                    if (catItem.length != 0) {

                        loop_();
                    }

                }, 50);
            }

        });


        $('#toggleFrontView .search').click(function () {

            var toggle = $('#toggleFrontView .search'),
                searchBtn = toggle.find('.search'),
                catBtn = toggle.find('.cats'),
                filterCats = $('#filterCategories'),
                searchHead = $('#searchHead'),
                searchBase = $('#searchBase');
            catItem = $('.catItem');

            toggle.addClass('active');
            $('#toggleFrontView .cats').removeClass('active');


            clearTimeout(animateIn);

            filterCats.removeClass('vis');
            catItem.removeClass('vis');
            searchBase.addClass('vis');
            searchBtn.removeClass('vis');
            //catBtn.removeClass('hidden');

            searchHead.find('h1').addClass('vis');
            searchHead.find('h2').removeClass('vis');

        });

        $scope.onImgLoad = function () {
            wall.fitWidth();
        };
```